# Is there a way to sort a database query output in descending order?

Tags: python, database, nosql, griddb

If I just ran a code which returned a table from a database, containing the results I want, how can I make the table go from bottom to top? Basically, it means I want the output to have the rows reversed. The rows at the bottom would start first and vice versa. Is there a way I can achieve this in Python?
I am running GridDB client on my computer. Please refer to the example below:

```py
'''
Old Output:
-- | id | value  | output |
-- |----|--------|--------|
-- | 1  | 100.05 | 0      |
-- | 2  | 101.02 | 0      |
-- | 3  | 112.34 | 0      |
-- | 4  | 124.35 | 1      |
-- | 5  | 156.00 | 1      |

New Output:
-- | id | value  | output |
-- |----|--------|--------|
-- | 5  | 156.00 | 1      |
-- | 4  | 124.35 | 1      |
-- | 3  | 112.34 | 0      |
-- | 2  | 101.02 | 0      |
-- | 1  | 100.05 | 0      |
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the inherited SQL commands in GridDB is the `ORDER BY` command. You can add it to the end of your search like so:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC
```

https://docs.griddb.net/sqlreference/sql-commands-supported/#order-by